# How do you know if a class is an annotation

Tags: java, reflection, java-annotations

how to juge a class is an annotation,

- How do you know if a class is an annotation

Is there a good Samaritan out there,,,,,,,
how to juge a class is an annotation

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source code: an annotation is declard as

```
@interface MyAnnotation { /* ... */ }
```

If you have some class object:

```
// Class<?> myClass = MyAnnotation.class;
if (myClass.isAnnotation()) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can like this:

```
if(class.hasMethodAnnotation(Annotation.class)){}
```

Comment: You can try this for standard java:
Class  clazz =YourAnnotation.class;
System.out.println(clazz.isAnnotation());

Comment: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do like this;

```
if (MyExampleClass.class.isAnnotationPresent(MyExampleAnnotation.class)) {
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).